# Made a method each for multiple Spinners - how to pass this data on to new activities?

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, methods, spinner

This might sound a bit convoluted. 
I have roughly 15 Spinners in one activity and made a distinct method for each of these spinners. I then initiate the methods in the onCreate method.

Method example:

```
 //Relative Position Spinner
public void relativePositionSpinner() {
    Spinner relativePositionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_relativePosition);

    ArrayAdapter relativePositionAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.relativePosition, R.layout.spinner_item);
    relativePositionSpinner.setAdapter(relativePositionAdapter);
    //what happens when selected
    relativePositionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

OnCreate Method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_hand);

    //initiate all Spinners
    relativePositionSpinner();
    absolutePositionSpinner();
etc.
```

Now what I want is to send the data of each Spinner to another Activity with the click of a Button. I know that I can do this with an intent and using putExtra in the Button method like this:

```
public void openHandSummary() {

    //Find the Button that gives option to enter new hand
    Button handInputButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hand_input_button);

    //set a click listener on Hand Analyzer Button
    handInputButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //below code will be executed when the new Hand Button is clicked
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent handSummaryIntent = new Intent(NewHandActivity.this, HandSummaryActivity.class);
            handSummaryIntent.putExtra("RelPosString", WHATTOENTERHERE??)
            startActivity(handSummaryIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

However I do not know how to retrieve the value/variable out of my Spinners to put them into the Button/intent method? Because if I make a String in the Spinner method, then I can't access this in the Button method.

So I feel like I have too many methods? So is there a way to pass data from one method to another method, or do I have to cancel some methods? What would be the easiest way to set this up?

I also made an onItemSelected to make some toasts, which worked. Can I use OnItemSelected somehow to create variables or initiate a data transfer to another Activity?

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    TextView myText = (TextView) view;
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner_relativePosition:
            makeText(NewHandActivity.this, "Relative Position is " + myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.spinner_absolutePosition:
            makeText(NewHandActivity.this, "Absolute Position is " + myText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
```

I'm very new to coding, and I just can't figure out the logic how I get the Spinner methods, Button/iniate method and OnItemSelected method to work together and exchange variables. Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Have already browsed the internet a day or so to find an answer, with no success.

Comment: I would recommend declaring `relativePositionSpinner` globally outside of any method. Then you can use this anywhere in your activity. `String[] relativePositionArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.relativePostion); Log.i(TAG,relativePositionArray[relativePositionSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your idea of separating out the code to create each spinner into its own method. However, if you are copying and pasting the whole method and making a few changes, you should step back and think about how you can do it even more easily. Often the changes you make after copy and paste give a hint that you should add some parameters to the method. If you do it correctly, you can write just a single method and then copy and paste the method **call** instead of the entire method and then make appropriate changes to the arguments.

As for your actual question, you are making this much more complicated than necessary. Specifically, you do not need to `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on any of the `Spinner`s. Instead, the `OnClickListener` for the button should just get the selected item from each spinner and send it to the new activity in the Intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints. Will definitely look into parameters and method call. Will also try to find a way by working with the button OnClickListener. Almost thought that I probably don't need the setOn...Listener but wasn't sure.